# How to completely disable code formatter in Intellij Idea 14?

Tags: intellij-idea

The code formatter in IJ14 is very annoying for me. 
Is there any way to disable it globally without putting @formatter tags into each file?

Comment: If the code formatter in IntelliJ 14 annoys you, why don't you downgrade, then?

Comment: Because v14 has some other great things that I like.